# Using matlab function block to output a histogram?

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram, simulink

I am using a Matlab function block in Simulink model. In my case, the Matlab function block takes in an arbitrary number of signals as input signals and outputs signal values over time in the form of a histogram.

I need a little guidance regarding how to start with matlab function block coding. I have read the documentation and various other posts but could not work my way around it, probably because its a new topic for me and i am not a matlab programmer. Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are new, try coding a simple MATLAB function outside of simulink which would be easier to debug. Checkout dsp.Histogram System object that can compute histogram over time.

Comment: i checked DSP.Histogram but that is not what I need. i specifically need to use matlab function block.

Comment: This is what i found on matlab Forum:

http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102364-how-do-i-get-a-histogram-from-the-histogram-block-of-the-dsp-blockset

DSP.histogram does not provide a histogram plot as an output, which is exactly what i need.